# combine parts from 2 different datetime variables into a new datetime variable

Tags: c#

I have 2 datetime objects that I need to combine.

This contains the correct date, but the time part is not needed.

```
DateTime? sessionDate = fl.EventDateTimeStart
```

This contains the correct time, but the date part needs to be the date value from the 
sessionDate object above.

```
DateTime? sessionStartTime = g.GameStartTime.Value
```

I tried using some of the various DateTime toString() methods, but found out that 
because they are part of a class, they need to remain DateTime? types 
so I can't just convert them to a string.

So I came up with this really ugly method:

```
                sessionStartTime = new DateTime(
                    fl.EventDateTimeStart.Value.Year, 
                    fl.EventDateTimeStart.Value.Month, 
                    fl.EventDateTimeStart.Value.Day, 
                    g.GameStartTime.Value.Hour, 
                    g.GameStartTime.Value.Minute, 
                    g.GameStartTime.Value.Second)
```

Is there a more elegant way of to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for improving working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
var result = fl.Value.Date + g.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

[`DateTime.Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a `DateTime` with the time part set to midnight. [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday?view=netframework-4.7.2) gets a `TimeSpan` containing the fraction of the day that has elapsed since midnight.

Make sure that both of your `DateTimes` have the same `Kind`, otherwise the result might not be what you expect.